# Searching with a Macro/VBA Using a Cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably a really easy thing that I am screwing up. I am working on a school project Creating an Inventory sheet.
My "Inventory" sheet has a bunch of product info on it.
My "Add Inventory" Sheet is set up with a VLOOKUP so when I scan my bar code it displays the row of information from the "Inventory sheet"
I made a macro button and recorded a Macro to try to edit the available inventory by clicking the button.
This is what I recorded.(the original I slaughtered trying to edit it but this should be the same)
Sub Macro7()
'

```
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Add Inventory").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Inventory").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="764666143326", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("K15").Select
    Sheets("Add Inventory").Select
    Range("K13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Inventory").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("L15").Select
End Sub
```

So my problem is the macro records the What:="764666143326" for the search with the bar code I was using for a sample. I need it to use the new bar code I scan on the next run. So I need it as a variable or to refence a cell. So I believe I need to set a Dim and a Range but have tried many times and watched a ton of videos with no success. I normally only use the record Macro button and don't not edit the VBA code. Please Help Me!!

EDIT:
Everying on this sheet is filled with VLOOKUP or a formula, except the yellow Cell B5, I scan the bar code into that cell.
[Add Inventory sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpXK8.png)

This is the page I want to edit with the Macro/VBA. I want it to search column C for the Bar code number I scanned into the "Add Inventory" sheet (which will change depending on what I am adding) and when it finds the matching bar code I want it to edit the "Quantity in Stock" or column K for that row of the matching bar code.

[Inventoy sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDuLH.png)

My problem is the macro I recorded saves what ever barcode I used for it not the cell as a variable.

Edit # 2
I think this show closer to what I am trying to do

```
Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Add Inventory").Select
    Range("K13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Inventory").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=Range("A1"), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate.Offset(0, 8).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Add Inventory").Select
    Range("B5").Select
End Sub
```

For this one I made Inventory cell A1 = ='Add Inventory'!B5

Also My bar codes are 12 digits.

Comment: It all comes down to copying the value in `K13` on `Add Inventory` to `K15` on `Inventory` and selecting `L15`. Can you explain what you are trying to do (e.g. with the found cell containing the bar code)? You should restrict the `Find` to a column and then explain what you want to copy where. Posting the screenshots of the worksheets would help a lot. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67048028/edit) your question at any time.

Comment: I edited my post does that help explain what I am trying to do?

Comment: So I want to copy to K? on Inventory the row will change based on the search. I have been unsuccessful at getting the search to us a variable, i.e. the new barcode I scanned on the Add Inventory sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I think there is a bigger problem with this method recorded by the macro recorder - this code will always select range "K15" regardless of what you search for.

I recommend you do not use the macro recorder, among other reasons it often creates code full of semantic errors - i.e. it works and it does does exactly what you tell it to do, which may not be the same as what you want it to do! As in the example above.

I would try something like this (you will need to check that the worksheets,  ranges and column numbers in the code below are correct for your project):

First we declare and assign a worksheet object, referring to your Inventory worksheet:

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = Sheets("Inventory")
```

Then we need to loop through every row on this worksheet and if the value in the barcode column matches a given search parameter, increase the value in the stock level column on that row, by the value of another cell on another sheet.

For this we will need a counter for the loop:

```
dim counter as integer
```

the search parameter:

```
dim searchParam as variant
searchParam = Sheets("Add Inventory").Range("B5").value
```

and the new value we want added to the current stock level:

```
dim newValue as variant
newValue = Sheets("Add Inventory").Range("K13").value
```

we need to tell Excel which column number to search in and which to change, I assumed you are adding stock to the inventory. You will need to change the column numbers below to suit your project

```
Dim barcodeColumnNumber As integer
Dim stockColumnNumber As integer

barcodeColumnNumber = 1
stockColumnNumber = 2
```

Now we add the loop

```
For counter = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    if ws.Cells(counter, barcodeColumnNumber) = searchParam then
        ws.Cells(counter, stockColumnNumber) = ws.Cells(counter, stockColumnNumber) + newValue
    End If

Next counter
```

Comment: I got  Compile error and Syntax error on

  if ws.Cells(counter, barcodeColumnNumber) = searchParam

I change the columns to 3 and 11

Comment: Is there a certain format I should have it in?? I have tried changing it between text general and number.

Comment: I missed the "then" which is incorrect syntax, apologies! I amended my answer.

Comment: No it shouldn't matter what format your cells are displayed in

Comment: That did it!!! I just had change the value being added to B13 instead of K13, K13 was already totaled for the new quantity. But this works perfect!! I am going to try to use this to create a macro to remove the inventory as well. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Come on 15 to count me

Answer (score 1):

### Update Inventory

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub addNewQuantity()
    
    ' Write lookup value (Bar Code) to a variable.
    Dim lValue As Long: lValue = Range("B5").Value
    
    ' Define range (to look for Bar Code).
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory")
        Dim fCell As Range:  Set fCell = .Range("C4")
        Dim lCell As Range: lCell = .Range(.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp)
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Range(fCell, lCell)
    End With
    
    ' Attempt to find the index (row) of a match.
    Dim cIndex As Variant: cIndex = Application.Match(lValue, rg, 0)
    
    If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
        ' Write new value to column 'K' (8 cells to the right from column 'C').
        rg.Cells(cIndex).Offset(, 8).Value = Range("K13").Value
        MsgBox "Bar Code ID '" & lValue & "' updated.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Bar Code ID '" & lValue & "' not found.", vbCritical, "Failure"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I got Compile error: and Syntax error on the first line : Dim 1Value as Long: 1Value=Range("B5").value

Comment: Is there a certain format I should have it in?? I have tried changing it between text general and number.

Comment: Variable names can't start with a number, so 1Value should be LValue or lValue like it is in VBasic2008's code.